# Excel - Generate Random Number based on 2 other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure how to accomplish the following task:
On columnA I have numbers, on columnB I have names associated to those numbers.

I would like to be able and generate a random number from column A, but only from the numbers that do not have anything associated on column B. For eg.: If I have a number in A1, but I do not have a name in B1, the number from A1 should be one of those that could be randomly generated.

If A2 has a number, and B2 is not empty (it has a name), I do not want to have A2 in the random range.

Also, it would be great to be able and re-generate the random number (aka, If I assign a number, let's say, 321, I want to be able somehow to generate the random number again, but it should not take into consideration 321 as it was already assigned).

I appreciate any ideas.

Sample

[image]

Comment: This is not a code-for-me site. This site is intended for specific questions and answers.

Comment: I added a few explanations to the thread.
@Grade'Eh'Bacon thanks for clearing that up. I hoped there is someone who mentions this.

Basically, using Python or JavaScript it would not be a problem. I just want to see if there is a built-in excel way of doing it.

Comment: You describe a spreadsheet where columns which in row B are blank have in row A a reference to =rand() (or similar), while columns which in row B have a value have in row A a number determined some other way. Press F9 to regenerate your references to =rand(). Good luck!

Comment: Note that any worksheet functions which use RAND will repopulate any time data is entered into your worksheet. You either need to generate the ID's dynamically [meaning all inputs must be unique with no duplicates, which is likely impossible if you intend on making 'random' numbers based on blank cells], or you need to use VBA.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I was assured now that all the numbers from column A are unique and always manually entered. Those are not randomly generated. It's clear now how Excel can do it.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

based on your sample data/spreadsheet, do the following:

1) in Cell C1: put the value "0"

2) in Cell C2: put the formula:

`=IF(ISBLANK(B2), 1, 0)+OFFSET(C2,-1,0,1,1)`

3) copy the formula in C2 down alongside all your data.

4) Put this formula anywhere you want to display the randomized # from Column A:

`=OFFSET(A1,MATCH(RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTA(A:A)-COUNTA(B:B)),C:C,0)-1,0,1,1)`

Comment: Thank you.
It worked like a charm. 
I also appreciate the walk through as it's easier to see the logic.

Comment: NP .. the only real downside to this guy is the "helper column" (which some people really really hate for some reason)  ;) lol  Anytime I use a helper column I try to use offset, so it doesn't "break" when you insert/delete a row ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have a hard time doing it with worksheet functions.  Here's one quick-and-dirty approach that works at least some of the time---

1. In two (or more) cells, add the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(COLUMN(A1),COLUMN(D1))`, replacing `A1` and `D1` with the first and last cells in your row of numbers.  This will pick random column numbers.
2. Give each of those cells a unique name, e.g., `therand`, `therand2`, ... .
3. In another cell, which will be your answer, add `=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,therand))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,therand)),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,therand2)))`.  This will check whether the first random column number corresponds to a blank label (`ISBLANK(...)`) and, if so, use the corresponding row-1 value.  If not, it will use the row-1 value from the second random column number.
4. Hit F9 to recalcualate.

This will not always give you a blank-labeled cell.  Add more random column numbers and corresponding `IF(...)` clauses to reduce the probability of a mis-selection.

**Edit**: you said "row A" in the original question, but I see you meant "column A" (rather than "row 1").  You'll need to transpose the rows and columns in the formulas above to make them work.

Comment: Thank you! 
I think I am looking at something like this, something easy. 
Let me check this quick and get back with a verdict.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, indeed, I meant columns.
Best wishes

Comment: I just thought of another option and it turns out @Ditto beat me to it :) .  Try that answer as well.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it seems simpler and works well. Thank you both @Ditto

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA answer. It can be used directly as a worksheet function:

```
Function RandUnassigned(R As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    Dim A As Variant, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim num As Long
    n = R.Rows.Count

    ReDim A(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        If Len(R.Cells(i, 2)) = 0 Then
            num = num + 1
            A(num) = R.Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    RandUnassigned = A(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, num))
End Function
```

Used like this:

[image]

This recalculates every time the spreadsheet does. If you want it to draw a random number just once, remove the line `Application.Volatile` from the function definition.

Comment: Thank you John,
This helps me understand how to transpose a Python code to something VB understands.

Comment: I do both a lot of Python and a lot of VBA and whenever I do VBA after doing Python for a while I find myself getting frustrated when I realize that I have to write 20 or 30 lines of VBA to get the functionality of a single Python list comprehension. Still -- VBA has its charms and there has been some interesting work done in making it possible to call Python from VBA. There is a nice blog which periodically discusses some of the issues: https://newtonexcelbach.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thank for this. Before I asked the question I have searched for an add-on that should facilitate this. Your blog recommendation is spot on. I appreciate it.